# Bootstrap Navbar not working when Responsive CSS not used

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using latest Bootstrap for designing my Admin panel. The Navbar I have included work fine when the Responsive css is include as below :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
```

But when I remove this line and reload the page, the Dropdown menus of Navbars does not work. Actually the dropdowns are working but they are getting overlapped under the container.

Any suggestion to solve this ?

Comment: used to this <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">

Comment: what I am asking is, I don't want to include the responsive css. I have it under 1 directory before that's why I have used ../ but actually I do not want it to be responsive, so when I removed that line, the Navbar stopped showing DROPDOWNS

Comment: Dont let us guessing ? Why not create a page or jsfiddle and show us the issue you are having . That way we can help ya better .

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Bootstrap.css AND bootstrap-responsive.css unless it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved now. I was using

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
```

In place of using

```
<div class="nav-collapse">
```

Thanks all for your time.